ECLiPSe create 2D matrix with C++ interfacing
I have a predicate that I use to initialise a 2D matrix in eclipse:
problem(1, [](
        [](1,2,3,4),
        [](1,2,4,3),
        [](1,3,2,4),
    )
).

I'd like to use a C++ program to interface with the set of eclipse predicates, and so I need a way to create the matrix from C++ with arbitrary values and dimensions. I can create a 1D matrix with
EC_functor matrix4("[]", 4);
EC_word r1 = term(matrix4, 1, 2, 3, 4);
EC_word r2 = term(matrix4, 1, 2, 4, 3);
EC_word r3 = term(matrix4, 1, 3, 2, 4);

and this doesn't cause any noticeable problems, but when I try to pack them into a 2d matrix it produces an error and terminates:
EC_functor matrix3("[]", 3);
EC_word table = term(matrix3, r1, r2, r3);

non-atomic initializer in ecl_refs_create()

How can I create a 2D matrix in C++ and pass it as a compound term argument?
(I couldn't find any examples of this in https://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/examples or https://eclipseclp.org/doc/embedding.pdf)

I cannot reproduce this problem with the code you posted, it works for me in both ECLiPSe versions 7.0 and 7.1.

The issue was accidently not included in my example in the question, but was to change the type of objects returned by term from EC_ref to EC_word.
I got confused by https://eclipseclp.org/doc/embedding.pdf#page=19 seeming to refer to interchangeability between the types.
